# Spring Async get current Executor

Tags: spring-boot, spring-async

I am using Spring `Async` by implementing [`AsyncConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html) and overriding the [`getAsyncExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html#getAsyncExecutor--) to define my `Executor`.
Now I would like to expose an endpoint, to return the current queue size, number of threads ...etc, of the Executor that is used by Async.
But I could not find a way to find or autowire the current executor that is used by Async.
I was thinking I can define a bean, that will be both used by the `getAsyncExecutor` method, and my reporting service.
But I was wondering if there is an easier/more appropriate way I can interact with async to get the current `Executor`.

My current config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-thread-");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);

        threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();

        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not define as bean. That is the best and easy option.

Comment: Define the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` as a bean AND call that method from the `getAsyncExecutor` method.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't registered a bean for the `ThreadPoolTaskExector`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        return taskExecutor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
       ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("async-thread-");
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(2);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
        threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);
        return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
    }
}
```

However Spring Boot 2.1 already pre-configures a `TaskExecutor` for you which you can configure through properties. You can then remove all config and only use `@EnableAsync` in your configuration.

```
spring.task.execution.pool.core-size=2
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size=2
spring.task.execution.pool.queue-capacity=100
spring.task.exection.thread-name-prefix=async-thread-
```

This configuration, together with a single `@EnableAsync` will achieve the same, without additional configuration.

With either configuration, you can now use `@Autowired` to get the instance in your service.